# Don't make functions within a loop error I can't fix

Tags: javascript, for-loop, jslint

So I'm using JSlint and I'm trying to implement the following code, but I'm getting the error message "Don't make functions within a loop error I can't fix". Any idea how I can alter my code to make this not receive errors/warnings?

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var blurInput = function () {
    this.blur();
};
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    (function (input) {
        input.addEventListener('focus', blurInput);
    })(inputs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Create the function outside and pass data into it

Comment: What is the point of that closure? You don't save `input` for use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to move your function outside your loop:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var blurInput = function () {
    this.blur();
};

// (rename this to something useful...)
var doSomething = function (input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', blurInput);
};

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    doSomething(inputs[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you kindly sir!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can just dispense with that closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener('focus', blurInput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would be using JsHint or EsLint you would be having options to disable that rule , but in  case of JsLint there is no option other than changing the structure of your code.

You can go with the change in code suggested by 'Frxstrem'